# Extend a TypeScript interface to allow its keys to be null

Tags: typescript

I'm using the CSS typings from `csstype` to set CSS style objects. However, I'd like to allow a CSS property to be null.

From what I understand, this should work:

```
import * as CSS from "csstype";

type CSSProperties = CSS.Properties<number | string>;

type CSSObject = CSSProperties & { [K in keyof CSSProperties]: CSSProperties[K] | null };

let k: CSSObject = {
  background: null
};
```

However, I get an error that `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | undefined'.`. I essentially want `CSSObject` to have all the same keys as `CSS.Properties`, but with each key also allowing a `null` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to `&` the whole object with the "or null" part on the right (talking about your third line). I don't have `'csstype'` at hand, so here's a quick demo with a random custom interface.

```
type OrNull<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | null }

interface Interface {
    a: number
    b: string
}

type InterfaceOrNull = OrNull<Interface>

const i: InterfaceOrNull = {
    a: null,
    b: null,
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20OrNull%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7C%20null%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Interface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20InterfaceOrNull%20%3D%20OrNull%3CInterface%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20i%3A%20InterfaceOrNull%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like `CSS.Properties` just expands the argument passed into it into the values of the object, you could simple add it to the `CSS.Properties` declaration:

```
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

type CSSProperties = CSS.Properties<number | string | null>;

let k: CSSProperties = {
  background: null,
  font: 'test',
  zIndex: 123,
  color: undefined
};
```